# Best approach for displaying nested comments using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I have the initial part working as far as displaying all of the data through a recursive partial, my issue now is figuring out how to display only specific number of tiers while hiding the children until a "show more" link is clicked under the last tier revealing all of the children.

A snippet of the data is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Parent Comment 1",
    "generation": 0,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [{"id": 3,
    "text": "Child of Parent 1",
    "generation": 1,
    "parentId": 1,
    "children": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "text": "Child of Child Parent 1",
        "generation": 2,
        "parentId": 3,
        "children": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "text": "Child of Child of Child Parent 1",
        "generation": 3,
        "parentId": 11
        },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "text": "Child of Parent 1",
        "generation": 1,
        "parentId": 1,
        "children": []
    }
```

In handlebars I am using a partial to render the children arrays nested under the parents:

```
<script id="childPartial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each children as |comment|}}
    <section>

{{#if children}}
{{>childPartial comment}} {{! Recursively render the partial }}
{{/if}}
</section>
{{/each}}
</script>
<script id="comments-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<div>
        {{#each comment_data as |comment|}} 

     </div>
        {{> childPartial comment}}


        </section>
        {{/each}} 
</script>
```

Is there a way to make a helper using handlebars that can hide the children that are of a certain generation lets say > 2 and to add a "show all.." link to the last child that is shown and then when clicked it will show all of the children?  Or is the best approach to use jquery and manipulate the markup after the context is templated?